# How do I change the date format?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, laravel

This is my js function to fetch data from database. The data is being dynamically appended data to my modal popup from the js page. Currently the date format shown, is "2018-06-09 15:43:44"(as stored in database). I wish to **change the date format that is being displayed** to dd-MMM-YYYY. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
function fetch(url, id) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url + id,
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $(`meta[name='_token']`).attr('content')
        },
        success: function (r) {
            let data = r;
//json value passed from controller in obj
            data = data.obj;
            let rows = '';
            $(data).each(function (index, row) {
                rows += `
                   <tr>
                            <td>${row.company_name}</td>
                            <td>${row.created_at}</td>
                   </tr>
            `;
            })
            $('.modalPage').html(rows);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `${row.created_at}` is js formatted? We need your php code

Comment: As you have tagged `laravel` so you can easily change the date format using `date()` function

Comment: yes @sta. This is js formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily override the default time format from the model but if you don't want to do that you can also define your own function in Javascript and use that function to convert the format.

You can use this

```
var my_date_format = function (input) {
   var d = new Date(Date.parse(input.replace(/-/g, "/")));
   var month = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 
   'Nov', 'Dec'];
   var date = d.getDay().toString() + " " + month[d.getMonth().toString()] + ", " + 
   d.getFullYear().toString();
   return (date);
};
```

and then call this function when the success method runs. like this.

```
success: function (r) {
        let data = r;
//json value passed from controller in obj
        data = data.obj;
        let rows = '';
        $(data).each(function (index, row) {
            rows += `
               <tr>
                        <td>${row.company_name}</td>
                        <td>${my_date_format(row.created_at)}</td>
               </tr>
        `;
        })
        $('.modalPage').html(rows);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...


$string = strtotime("2018-06-09 15:43:44") // row.created_at in your case;
$date = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($string);
return $date->format('d/m/Y'); // desired format.
```

For Date formats check this https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

code should be ideally in controller and pass this formatted date from there to view. Or better you can define accessor.

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 0):

Use the [date.format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) library: :

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
var today= new Date(); 
var dateString = today.format("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Comment: it says require is not defined

Comment: try this code 

<?php
$date=date_create("2020-03-15");
echo date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
?>

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp]

Answer (score 0):

Convert in sql like this,

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 105);
```

Look more format on [this link](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-system-functions/convert-datetime-to-string/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use laravel or any javascript package for date functions you can define your own functions like below.

```js
let myDate = new Date("2020-08-11 20:59");

const formatNumbers = function(num) {
  return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}

const formatDate = function (date){
  let day = formatNumbers(date.getDate());
  let month = formatNumbers(date.getMonth() + 1);
  let year = date.getFullYear()
  console.log(date)
  return day + '-' +  month + '-' + year
}

document.getElementById('formattedDate').innerHTML = formatDate(myDate);
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="givenDate">Given Date: 2020-08-11 20:59</span>
</div>
<div>
  Formatted Date: <span id="formattedDate"></span>
</div>
```

This code block is for your specific need if you want to create more generic formatter you can imrove your functions with following this documentation [MDN Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)