# How to get dd-mm-yyyy format date in datatable laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, date, datatable, datatables

I get the serverside data from controller, and get data using ajax. This is my datatable script.

```
// Data table
        var table = $('.data-table').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            responsive: true,
            ajax: "quotation",
            dom: '<"top"fB>rt<"bottom"lip><"clear">',
            columns: [{
                    data: 'quotation_no',
                    name: 'quotation_no'
                },
                {
                    data: 'remarks',
                    name: 'remarks'
                },
                {
                    data: 'quotation_date',
                    name: 'quotation_date'
                },
                {
                    data: 'quotation_category',
                    name: 'quotation_category'
                },
                {
                    data: 'quotation_status',
                    name: 'quotation_status'
                },
                {
                    data: 'action',
                    name: 'action',
                    orderable: false,
                    searchable: false
                },
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [
                [10, 25, 50, -1],
                [10, 25, 50, "All"]
            ],
        });
```

default format for quotation_date is yyyy-mm-dd . How to make dd-mm-yyyy?

Comment: Can you show your controller action?

Comment: `quotation_date.split(/\W/).reverse().join('-')`. Or from scratch: `new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-GB').replace(/\W/g,'-')`. Or [*How do I change the date format?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371073/how-do-i-change-the-date-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like this in the Model.

```
/**
    * The attributes that should be cast.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $casts = [
       'quotation_date' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
    ];
```

Or, alternatively you can also use [Carbon Date](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) in the controller:

```
$quotationDate = Carbon::parse($item['quotation_date'])->format('d-m-Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add in your model $casts attr if you use eloquent for getting data from DB.

```
protected $casts = [
    'quotation_date' => 'datetime:d-m-Y',
];
```

After it action your date format will be like dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of @Paresh.